# Vue: Data fields changing as inputs are edited

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Editing to remove component names but basically trying to use v-modal to get component data inside.
Editing to remove component names but basically trying to use v-modal to get component data insideEditing to remove component names but basically trying to use v-modal to get component data inside
**wp.vue . (Modal component inside template as Child component)**

```
<template>
    <div class="cart-component">
        <Modal
            :modal-type="this.modalType"
            :customer="this.customer"
        >
       <div class="shipping-info">
            <span class="title">Shipping Address</span>
            <span class="personal-details">{{this.customer.street_address + "," + this.customer.city + "," + this.customer.state}}</span>
            <span 
                data-toggle="modal" 
                v-on:click="() => {this.modalType = 'EditShipping'}"
                data-target="#"
                class="edit">Edit
            </span>
        </div>

</template>

<script>
    import Modal from './Modal.vue';

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                cart: [],
                cartItems: [],
                customer: {},
                dataLoaded: false,
                modalType: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getCartItems()
        },
        components: {
            'Modal': Modal
        },
        methods: {
            getCartItems: function() {
                axios
                    .get('/api/new-account/cart')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.cart = response.data.cart;
                        this.cartItems = response.data.cart.items;
                        this.customer = response.data.customer;
                        this.dataLoaded = true;
                    });
            }
</script>
```

**S.vue (child of Shop.vue)**

```
<template>
    <div class="shipping-input-containers">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="first-name">
                <input v-model="customer.name.split(` `)[0]" class="default-input"></input>
                <span class="input-small">First Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="last-name">
            <input v-model="customer.name.split(` `)[1]" class="default-input"></input>
            <span class="input-small">Last Name</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="street-address">
        <input v-model="customer.street_address" class="default-input"></input>
        <span class="input-small">Street Address</span>

    </div>
    <div class="city">
        <input v-model="customer.city" class="default-input"></input>
                <span class="input-small">City</span>
    </div>
    <div class="state">
        <input v-model="customer.state" class="default-input"></input>
        <span class="input-small">State</span>
    </div>
    <div class="zip-code">
        <input v-model="customer.zip" class="default-input"></input>
        <span class="input-small">Zip Code</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
      props: {
                 customer: {type: Object}
      },
      methods: {
             updateShippingAddress: function() {
                    axios.post('/api/account/update-address', { 
                         street_address: this.customer.street_address || "",
                         city: this.customer.city || "",
                         country_code: this.customer.country_code || "",
                         state: this.customer.state || "",
                         zip: this.customer.zip || "",
                         apartment: this.customer.apartment || "",
                         phone_number: 221232123,
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                              if(response.data.success) {
                                 this.$parent.getCartItems();
                                 let msg = "Address updated!"
                                 this.showFlashMsg(msg, true)
                              }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {


                    });
             }
      }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you use same model between Shop and Modal, it works like that.
First of all, you need to use new name such as “customer.newCity” in the Modal.
And then when users update via updateShippingAddress, you can POST the user’s city like this :

```js
//...
city: this.customer.newCiity ? this.customer.newCity : (this.customer.city || "")
//...
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/MxBmJg - While this is true, and I 100% agree with this - you could still use the same model in Shop and Modal, just not use `v-model` to bind in the Modal. `v-model` is a two way data binding.

Comment: @MattOestreich This is great and super informative -- exactly what I was looking for to help me understand it.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @MattOestreich I agree with you. Thanks for your help :)